# Weird edges in OpenGL 2d rendering

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

[image]

As you can see pointed out by the arrows there are some weird edges next to my textures.

Here is my OpenGL setup:

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, WINDOW_WIDTH, 0, WINDOW_HEIGHT, 1, -1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

And here my rendering code:

```
glPushMatrix();
    Color.white.bind();

    texture.bind();


    glTranslatef(position.x+size.width/2, position.y+size.height/2, 0f);
    glRotatef(rotation, 0f, 0f, 1f);
    glTranslatef(-size.width/2, -size.height/2, 0f);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        glVertex2f(0, 0);

        glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        glVertex2f(size.width-1, 0);

        glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        glVertex2f(size.width-1, size.height-1);

        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex2f(0, size.height-1);
    glEnd();

glPopMatrix();
```

I've read that the default mode in OpenGL is to repeat the texture if the object is bigger than the texture, but in my case thats not true.

**EDIT:**

Code to load the texture (I use a library for that (slick-util)):

```
texture = TextureLoader.getTexture(textureLocation.substring(0, textureLocation.lastIndexOf('.')), ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream(textureLocation));
```

And I add the texture parameters right after I set up OpenGL, is that correct?

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, WINDOW_WIDTH, 0, WINDOW_HEIGHT, 1, -1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

Comment: still rounding errors can put the text coordinate outside the texture, use clamp is needed

Comment: @ratchetfreak Can you elaborate or post an answer?

Comment: You mean like this? `glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL11.GL_CLAMP);` I tried, but it doesnt work either.

Comment: `GL_CLAMP` is wrong, coupled with linear interpolation that will wrap around to the other side of the image when it comes time to fetch the 4 nearest texels for filtering if you do not have any border texels. `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` is what you want, and in fact, `GL_CLAMP` and border texels do not even exist in *modern* GL.

Comment: Edges are still there.

Comment: Post your code where you load the texture, i.e. where the glTexParameteri and all that stuff is

Comment: Could you also add the texture file itself for inspection?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you are using an atlas (or spritesheet) and that your character is being surrounded by other sprites that cause these edges. To prevent that from happening, you should add a tiny offset to your UV coordinates. Usually a quarter of a pixel will solve all the problems. By doing so, you should know that you have to take the total width and height of the texture into account, because UV values are in the range (0,1). So, offset all your UV inside the sprite by this amount:

```
x-offset = 1.0 / (textureWidth * 4.0);
y-offset = 1.0 / (textureHeight * 4.0);
```

Comment: Padding the textures in an atlas by just 1px would be better

Comment: @KromStern: Look at where the edges are. He pads them with almost 30 pixels.

Comment: Padding should be made outside of the UV coordinates he use, not inside. If you have 32x32 sprite, padded 30px, but sample UVs 92x92px .. well, you will have neighbor sprites if those are not padded, which could be that case.

Comment: @KromStern: Yes, indeed. He seems to pad them a lot, but ruins the idea of padding by making the UV's touch the neighboring sprites.

Answer (score 1):

Answering Martijin's notice above: this is actually not atlas texture, it is enough to check  glTexCoord2f, which shows that complete texture is used as quad.

Also there is no information on type of texture. It could be jpg with some artifacts, and blending or shader could skip some texture values leaving artifacts.

If it is, try to use tga or png with alpha channel.

Stretching could also cause artifacts. Is your glViewport having same size as glOrtho?

Answer (score -1):

When are you setting your texture parameters? Don't know if it'll help, but I tend to use the following (it's c, but the translation to java should be straight forward).

```
glGenTextures(2, node->textures);
GRL2_BindTexture(GL_TEXTURE1, GL_TEXTURE_2D, node->textures[0]);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, 
                GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB,
             128, 128, 0, GL_RGB,
             GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*) node->colorMap);
```

In short, I set the texture parameters after I create and bind the texture, but before uploading. Don't know if it'll help, but anythings possible.

Another thing to check is the size of you're texture. Is it a power of 2? Some graphic cards can be rather sticklers about this.